# Python Socket Programming client not receiving all packets

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

So i was learning the concept of Python Network Programming using Sockets.
I tried to create a simple messaging app in which there is a server , a sender and a receiver. 
The sender sends the message to the server , and the server passes to the receiver which is then displayed in the receiver.

But the main problem is , when i send a message from the sender , the message after every 3 messages sent is being printed , rest all are lost/ignored.
Here are the code snippets.

Server.py :

```
import socket
from threading import *

c = None #Client socket1
addr = None #Client address1
c2 = None #Client socket2
addr2 = None #Client address2

server_socket1 = socket.socket() #by default it is SOCK_STREAM (TCP) and has porotocal AF_INET (IPv4) 

server_socket1.bind(('localhost',9999)) #server machine's ip and port on which it will send and recieve connections from

server_socket1.listen() 
print("Server started successfully!!!")
print("Waiting for connections...\n\n")

while (((c is None)and(addr is None)) and ((c2 is None) and (addr2 is None))):
    if((c is None) and (addr is None)):
        c,addr = server_socket1.accept()
        print("User connected to client1 socket!!")
        c.send(bytes("Connected to the apps server!!!","utf-8"))
        name = c.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Client connected with name "+name+ " ip address "+str(addr))
        c.send(bytes("******Welcome to Messenger Lite "+name+" ******","utf-8"))

    if((c2 is None) and (addr2 is None)):
        c2,addr2 = server_socket1.accept()
        print("\n\nUser connected to client2 socket!!")
        c2.send(bytes("\n\nConnected to the apps server!!!","utf-8"))
        name2 = c2.recv(1024).decode()
        print("Client connected with name "+name2+ " ip address "+str(addr2))
        c.send(bytes("******Welcome to Messenger Lite "+name2+" ******","utf-8"))


while True:
    if(c.recv(1024)!=None):
        msg = c.recv(1024).decode()
        c2.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))
```

Sender.py :

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket() #by default it is SOCK_STREAM (TCP) and has porotocal AF_INET (IPv4) 

client_socket.connect(('192.168.217.1',9999)) #server machine's ip and port on which it will send and recieve connections from
name = input ("Enter your name : ")
client_socket.send(bytes(name,"utf-8"))

print(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
print(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())

while True:
        message = input("\n\nEnter a message : ")
        client_socket.send(bytes(message,"utf-8"))
        print("Message Sent!!!")
```

Receiver.py :

```
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket() #by default it is SOCK_STREAM (TCP) and has porotocal AF_INET (IPv4) 

client_socket.connect(('192.168.217.1',9999)) #server machine's ip and port on which it will send and recieve connections from
name = input ("Enter your name : ")
client_socket.send(bytes(name,"utf-8"))

print(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
print(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())

while True:
    if(client_socket.recv(1024).decode()):
        print(client_socket.recv(1024).decode())
```

Here the logic is , that when the server starts , first the sender connects , then the receiver connects , the variables in the server.py are initialized accordingly.

But the output looks like this :

[Right is the Sender window and left is the receiver window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7UJU.png)

As clearly seen in the image , all the messages in between get ignored and messages after ever 3 messages are being printed. What may be the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is discarding some incoming messages because you are calling `recv()` without using what it returns.

I would rewrite this:

```py
while True:
    if(c.recv(1024)!=None):
        msg = c.recv(1024).decode()
        c2.send(bytes(msg,"utf-8"))
```

as:

```py
while True:
    msg = c.recv(1024)
    if(msg != None):
        msg = msg.decode()
        c2.send(bytes(msg, "utf-8"))
```

Comment: I tried it but it is still printing messages alternatively. One message is still being left out in between.